# magento 1.9 : anchor tag not working in language translation

Tags: magento-1.9, translate

I want to place anchor tag in given text>so i kept like this

```
   <?php    $var=Mage::getBaseUrl();
   echo $this->__("Iam <a href='%s'>here</a> with link",$var) ?>
```

I wrote translations for

```
      Iam here with link in csv file but it is not translating
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution.Need to add anchor tag in csv file as well

```
   Iam <a href='%s'>here</a> with link
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split into parts first before "a" text then under the "a" text and then after the "a" text split into three part with echo $this->__(""); 
thanks